# What does "foster" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean encourage or nurture?
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/foster_1?q=foster

“There is never enough time — for work, for family and friends — and it takes work to make the best use of it,” he said. “It’s all about fostering a holistic perspective in life.”

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/10/06/spotify-ceo-i-start-my-workday-at-1030-ama-look-at-his-morning-routine.html

Comment: There are several rather vague words there, put together to make a rather vague idea, but to me it doesn't seem to have any meaning beyond the meanings of the words. Please look the words up in a good dictionary, and if you still don't understand, edit your question to show precisely what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Yes, _foster_ does mean to encourage or nurture.

Comment: I think haile is asking which of the two it means, @KateBunting. My answer is that in this metaphorical use, there is not really any difference.